# передача массива через конструктор

Tags: java, массивы

Задача:
Передать массив в конструкторе.

```
public Tensor(T[] other, int m){
    this.m = m;

}
```

Вопрос:
Как указать что массив будет размером m. T -это параметризированый тип. голову ломаю уже несколько часов. в каком направлении копать?

Comment: Возможно, есть некоторая путаница в понятиях между java и c++. Правильно ли я понимаю, что Вы хотите создать массив внутри класса Tensor?

Comment: я уже разобрался. Тут получается конструктор дженерика. в него передается массив. m- это количество элементов. я просто через обычный if проверил размер массива, и в случае если true то заполняю коллекцию, если else то выкидывает пока строчку, потом сделаю Exception. Возможно и путаница в понятиях. Как то так. Я просто как старый пес понимаю а сказать не могу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак, java не поддерживает проверку длин массивов при передаче в качестве аргумента из коробки. Вы всегда можете проверить этот размер вручную и выкинуть `InvalidArgumentException` в случае передачи неверного значения, но вряд ли этим должен заниматься конструктор. В случае, если вы передаете сложные конструкции, возможно, стоит описать пользовательский класс, который будет этим заведовать.

Comment: я с плюсов переписываю проект. постоянно натыкаюсь на C++ может java не может.

Answer (score 0):

в конечном итоге получилось так, вроде отработало.

```
 public Tensor(T[] other, int m){
    if (other.length == m){
        this.addAll(Arrays.asList(other));
    } else {
        System.out.println("impossible, later it'll be exception");
    }
```